# Add list items of one list to another list of list at same index

Tags: python, list

How can I achieve the below result? Both the list have same index size.

```
list_1 = [ 'arn1', 'arn2' ]

list_2 =[
    ['abc', '123'],
    ['pqr' , '789']
]

expected_output = [ 
    ['abc', '123', 'arn1'],
    ['pqr' , '789', 'arn2']
]
```

Comment: Does `list_1` only contain strings?

Answer (score 2):

When trying to combine two lists item by item, `zip` is something you should always start with.

```
zip(list_1, list_2)
```

In this case, what you want is:

```
[ys + [x] for x, ys in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Which gives:

```
[['abc', '123', 'arn1'], ['pqr', '789', 'arn2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use enumerate to loop to the first list, get the index then append to the second list.

```
list_1 = [ 'arn1', 'arn2' ]

list_2 =[
    ['abc', '123'],
    ['pqr' , '789']
]

for i, item in enumerate(list_1):
    list_2[i].append(item)

print(list_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly longer solution, but simpler:

```
list_1 = ['arn1', 'arn2']

list_2 = [['abc', '123'], ['pqr', '789']]

expected_output = [['abc', '123', 'arn1'], ['pqr', '789', 'arn2']]

output = []
for i in range(0, len(list_1)):  # iterates 
    added_list = list_2[i] + [list_1[i]]
    output.append(added_list)
print(output == expected_output)
# True
```

Or a list comprehension, if you want one:

```
output_list_comprehension = [list_2[i] + [list_1[i]] for i in range(0, len(list_1))]
#returns same answer
```